# Why is JRequest::getVar() not returning anything in my custom profile/registration plugin?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I've made an extra custom field called **esrnumber**. I've added a `onUserBeforeSave()`function to the php file within the plugin. This is supposed to take the esrnumber from my custom field as well as the name from the registration form, check a database, and return true if they match. Thus allowing the user to register.

The problem is that i can't seem to get the field values from the form into this php script. Below is my code.

```
function onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $new){
//sql code removed for example
    $foundesr = false;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['esrnumber'])) {
    $test = $_GET['esrnumber'];
    } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['esrnumber']))         {
        $test = $_POST['esrnumber'];
    } else {
        $test = "booo";
    }
   if($foundesr == false){
        JError::raiseWarning(1000, JText::_('There is a problem with your ESR number, ' . JRequest::getVar('username') . JRequest::getVar('esrnumber') . JRequest::getVar('jform_username') . $test . 'it does not match that name in our records.'));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As you can see most of that is unnecessary, I've just tried several different methods to retrieve the value from the registration form fields, everyone of them returns empty. Where am i going wrong? How can i simply get the values from my form into this method?

Here's the *HTML* code Joomla generates for the form (asfaik this is all default stuff)

```
<div class="registration">
<form id="member-registration" action="/index.php/component/users/?task=registration.register" method="post" class="form-validate">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>User Registration</legend>
                <dl>
                                <dt>
                <span class="spacer"><span class="before"></span><span class="text"><label id="jform_spacer-lbl" class=""><strong class="red">*</strong> Required field</label></span><span class="after"></span></span>                                    </dt>
            <dd>&#160;</dd>
                                            <dt>
                <label id="jform_name-lbl" for="jform_name" class="hasTip required" title="Name::Enter your full name">Name:<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>                                   </dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="jform[name]" id="jform_name" value="pirateballoon@gmail.com" class="required" size="30"/></dd>
                                            <dt>
                <label id="jform_username-lbl" for="jform_username" class="hasTip required" title="Username::Enter your desired user name">Username:<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>                                   </dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="jform[username]" id="jform_username" value="pirateballoon@gmail.com" class="validate-username required" size="30"/></dd>
                                            <dt>
                <label id="jform_password1-lbl" for="jform_password1" class="hasTip required" title="Password::Enter your desired password - Enter a minimum of 4 characters">Password:<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>                                    </dt>
            <dd><input type="password" name="jform[password1]" id="jform_password1" value="" autocomplete="off" class="validate-password required" size="30"/></dd>
                                            <dt>
                <label id="jform_password2-lbl" for="jform_password2" class="hasTip required" title="Confirm Password::Confirm your password">Confirm Password:<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>                                    </dt>
            <dd><input type="password" name="jform[password2]" id="jform_password2" value="" autocomplete="off" class="validate-password required" size="30"/></dd>
                                            <dt>
                <label id="jform_email1-lbl" for="jform_email1" class="hasTip required" title="Email Address::Enter your email address">Email Address:<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>                                 </dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="jform[email1]" class="validate-email required" id="jform_email1" value="pirateballoon@gmail.com" size="30"/></dd>
                                            <dt>
                <label id="jform_email2-lbl" for="jform_email2" class="hasTip required" title="Confirm email Address::Confirm your email address">Confirm email Address:<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>                                   </dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="jform[email2]" class="validate-email required" id="jform_email2" value="pirateballoon@gmail.com" size="30"/></dd>
                                                                            </dl>
    </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                <legend>User ESR Profile</legend>
                <dl>
                                <dt>
                <label id="jform_esrprofile_esrnumber-lbl" for="jform_esrprofile_esrnumber" class=" required">ESR Number<span class="star">&#160;*</span></label>                                   </dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="jform[esrprofile][esrnumber]" id="jform_esrprofile_esrnumber" value="" class="required"/></dd>
                            </dl>
    </fieldset>
        <div>
        <button type="submit" class="validate">Register</button>
        or          <a href="/" title="Cancel">Cancel</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="registration.register" />
        <input type="hidden" name="b44564159b9c7ebe3b7caf93cc5ce8de" value="1" />       </div>
</form>
```

I personally never called that new method i made, i just created the method and Joomla seems to automatically call it upon submitting the form.

Cheers.

Comment: You have to pass the values to the `onUserBeforeSave` function as parameter.

Comment: Hi, how do i do that? The guide i followed didn't mention that. Would it be the $user or $new parameter? Surely it would be the $new parameter as there is no held details on that user yet. If so where do i tell it to pass the values on?
The function seems to be called fine when the user clicks submit.

Comment: can you please show your code where you have called that `onUserBeforeSave` function.

Comment: I added the function to the php file you see in this plugin package

[http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin)

The function automatically gets called when the user clicks submit.

Comment: I want you to show the code where you call this function,not where yu define that function

Comment: post your html code as well. so I will be able to help you out

Comment: Thanks guys. I know what you mean, but i never personally called that function anywhere. I just made the function in the plugin's php file, and Joomla automatically calls that function when the registration form is submitted. 
Edited my first post with the HTML of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. If anybody finds this thread and needs to know, this is how i did it in the `onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $new)` function.

```
JArrayHelper::getValue($new, 'name', 0, 'STRING')
```

Gives you your variable. Just change where it says name to get whichever user details you want. To get the ESR number (my custom field) i had to do this:

```
        foreach ($new['esrprofile'] as $k => $v) {
             $esrnumber = $v;
        }
```

There's probably a more efficient way of getting that esr number out of that array seeing as how i think there's only one instance of the number in there, but this works for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$fields = $jinput->get('jform','','array');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all JRequest is deprecated and should not be used in 2.5 and it is completely removed in the new Joomla 3.0. Instead use [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) like so:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$fields = $jinput->getArray('jform');
```

Now you should be able to reference yout fields like so:

```
$fields['name'];
$fields['username'];
etc.
```

Comment: I tried that but it seems to break on the `$fields = $jinput->getArray('jform');` line. It just makes a white screen. I tried changing it to `$fields = $jinput->getArray($new);` That didn't break it but it seemed to just be returning empty.

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable error display to see what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using *JRequest* to retrieve the input you can use the `$new` variable instead:

```
echo $new->username;
echo $new->email;
```

However, the reason `JRequest::getVar` is not working is simply because you are using the wrong names. It seems like you are trying to use the IDs of the input fields and not the name.

The input names is set to *jform[name]* etc. So to retrieve them using *JRequest* get the whole array:

```
$jform = JRequest::getVar('jform');
$username = $jform['username'];
```

Also, if you are using a Joomla version > 2.5 see *JInput*:
http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput